# Netbeans for Intel appup development

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Has anyone used Netbeans for developing apps for the Intel Appup Store. I know they 'officially' support Eclipse. I downloaded the Java SDK, packed and validated my jar file, which then stops working. The report says that *appup_sdk_javav.xxx* is absent in the */lib* folder. But it's there.
I add that file by adding it through Netbeans. Is it the problem with Netbeans or something else is wrong.

Comment: Suggestion: make sure your compile and runtime lib paths are the same. I've had problems on NetBeans where compile works ok, run doesn't as the library paths were different.

Comment: ensured this,still not working(BTW Can you give a more detailed info)